# dax evaluate table error: ABC doesn't exist, or there is no current row for a column named ABC

Tags: sql-server, dax, ssas-tabular

Just want to do basic query of the tables:

In db2 running

```
evaluate [Table_1]
```

yields

> Query (1, 10) The value for 'Table_1' cannot be determined. Either
>   'Table_1' doesn't exist, or there is no current row for a column named
>   'Table_1'.
>   [image]

---

I verified the row count

[image]
Could anybody help? Thanks-

Comment: The message sounds like your table is empty. What do the rows of your table look like?

Comment: thank you @AlexisOlson are you talking about another way to see the rows? I couldn't see the rows, just saw the error in OP. I verified the row counts - see OP pls.

Comment: I think it means you may be returning too many rows so there isn't one current one available to return?